# When browser window resolution changes,how can I adjust my app resolution in angular 4

Tags: angular, browser, resolution

Need to fix screen resolution according to changes in browser resolutiom in angular 4.Is it through viewport ,  or through chromedriver & webdriver.

Comment: You need to follow Responsive Web Design Mobile First Approach. To Achieve this, you need to use CSS library Bootstrap 4, Ionic etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular, you can use [Cdk Layout](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) and/or [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)... Which contains directives for grid as well.